# How can the nested loops of unknown layers be implemented by recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, cycle

int m =10;

```
    int n = 9;

    int p = 4;

    int q = 7;

    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){

        int a = i;

        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){

            int b = j;

            if(b==a){

                continue;

            }

            for(int k=0;k<p;k++){

                int c = k;

                if(c==b || c==a){

                    continue;

                }

                for(int l=0;l<q;l++){

                    int d = l;

                    if(d==c || d==b || d==a){

                        continue;

                    }

                    System.out.println("i="+i+",j="+j+",k="+k+",l="+l);

                }

            }

        }

    }
```

For example, the code fragment is a four layer nested loop, and the loop between has data dependencies, and nested layers is uncertain, how it will achieve through the recursive (nested is uncertain)?

Comment: What have you tried so far to get recursion to work?

Comment: I have a problem at work, it has to be solved by cycle, and the number of cycles is uncertain and has to be implemented by recursive method, but I don't know how to do it

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/recursion-in-java this tutorial show you how to use recursive..

Comment: Thank you very much, but it still doesn't solve my doubts. Can you write the code for the question?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a coding service. If you have a doubt, you can rephrase your question. The tutorial is a good point for learning how to solve this problem

Comment: Well, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void recurse(int[] a, int[] b, int depth) {
    if (depth == a.length) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
        return;
    }

    outer:
    for (int i = 0; i < a[depth]; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < depth; j++) {
            if (i == b[j]) {
                continue outer;
            }
        }
        b[depth] = i;
        recurse(a, b, depth + 1);
    }
}
```

Sample call:

```
recurse(new int[] {10, 9, 4, 7}, new int[4], 0);
```

Comment: Wow, you're great!How did you do that?I admire you a lot！

Comment: Stackoverflow is really a nice place，Thank stackoverflow

Comment: I have another question to ask you,
Give you two integer arrays a, b and an integer c (greater than or equal to 0), add all the elements of array a plus the integer c equal to the sum of all the elements of array b, and each element of array a represents a transaction detail data, each element of the array b represents a summary transaction data, the integer c represents the fee

Comment: How to find an efficient algorithm, so that each transaction summary data corresponding to a number of detailed data, as far as possible so that the summary data is equal to the sum of the detailed data, If not equal, borrow from c, to ensure that the fee is just enough, and each element of a does not repeat or miss

Comment: such as,

input: int [] a = new int {2,4,6,1,3,8,5}; int [] b = new int {15,14}; int c = 0;

output: 15 = {6,1,8}, 14 = {2,4,3,5}

Comment: Another example:

input: int [] a = new int {2,4,6,1,8,5}; int [] b = new int {22,9}; int c = 5;

output: 22 = {2,4,6,1,8,1 (split from 5)}, 9 = {5,4 (split from 5)}

Comment: Looking forward to your reply